# Download file from filepath/uri using .Net

Tags: c#, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I'm looking to replace WebClient with HttpClient. Currently the WebClient is being fed a path to the file that can either be a HTTP/S or a local/shared file.  As HttpClient only supports HTTP/S endpoints is there any out-of-the-box solution to this or do I need to check the file path and use HttpClient if it's pointing to a HTTP/S endpoint and FileStream if it's local?
This is currently a .Net Framework 4.7 solution but I'm working on upgrading it to .Net Core 7/8.

I've tried using HttpClient only.